# How do you handle spaces in variables when using C# interpolation?

Tags: c#, interpolation

With string interpolation, how do you handle variables piped into a command that contain spaces in them? For example, if you have a variable that has spaces in it (like a UNC path), how do you handle that?

This code works when no spaces are present in the "filePath" variable (i.e.; \ServerName\testfile.txt):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", $"use X: \\{filePath} {pwd /USER:{usr}").WaitForExit();
```

As soon as you encounter a path that has spaces in it, however, the command above no longer works, because it's unable to find the path. Normally, I would apply quotes around a path containing spaces, to counter this (in other languages like PowerShell). How do you do something similar with C# interpolation.

Comment: I'd apply quotes around a path containing spaces. Either stick the quotes in the $ string (they're harmless if they're not needed), or write an extension method to String that quotes the string if needed.

Comment: I dont think this question has anything to do with string interpolation.  Your problem is related to path encoding / wrapping path in quotes.  You would have the same issue with string formatting, string concatenation, etc

Comment: feels like you are expecting string interpolation to do things it doesnt do (like run commands), variables in c# dont have spaces in their names. YOu will have to run 'pwd' yourself

Comment: C# variable names can't have spaces in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this in c# just the way you would in the command line

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", $"use X: \"\\{filePath}\" {pwd /USER:{usr}").WaitForExit();
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for this command. However, the same doesn't seem to work for this command (have tried it several different ways). System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("robocopy.exe", $@"X:\ ""C:\users\username\Desktop\Test"" {filename}").WaitForExit();

Comment: hmmm... are you sure you sure you are escaping your strings? it doesn't look like it from the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have anything to do with string interpolation, it has to do with how the executable parses the command line. Single arguments that have spaces in them (like a path) should be wrapped in quotes so they're treated as one argument and not several.

You can add quotes inside a string by escaping the quote character with a backslash character (`\"`):

```
var filePath = @"\\server\share\directory with spaces";
var usr = $"{Environment.UserDomainName}\\{Environment.UserName}";

System.Diagnostics.Process
    .Start("net.exe", $"use X: \"{filePath}\" pwd /USER:{usr}")
    .WaitForExit();
```

This is also true ***without*** string interpolation:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process
    .Start("net.exe", string.Format("use X: \"{0}\" pwd /USER:{1}", filePath, usr))
    .WaitForExit();
```